# NameValuePair Alternative without use org.apache.http.legacy

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have one application which have `Asynctask` used in it with help of `org.apache.http.legacy` library. As you all know this is deprecated and so I want remove it. If I do not complie that library then I am only getting one error in it called **Can not resolved symbol 'NameValuePair'**

My code for same is like below.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {


    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(DataManager.TAG_APPS_URL, "POST", params);
    DataManager.arrayList_appItem.clear();
    try {
        products = json.getJSONArray(DataManager.TAG_ROOT);

        for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

            String name = c.getString(DataManager.TAG_APP_NAME);
            String url = c.getString(DataManager.TAG_APP_URL);
            String image = c.getString(DataManager.TAG_APP_IMAGE);

            appItem = new AppItem(name,url,image);
            DataManager.arrayList_appItem.add(appItem);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: if you really want to get rid of legacy code, you should use okHTTP, retrofit or volley for network calls.

Comment: Get rid of whatever `jParser` is, or do not use it to perform the HTTP requests.

Comment: `params` has nothing in it...

Comment: @cricket_007 I do not understood

Comment: `params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();` and you use it on the next line. You have no parameters. You don't even need that list. Where did you even get this `JSONParser` class?

Comment: Anyways, Retrofit. It has a learning curve, but I'd bet you all major apps use it. https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en

Comment: @cricket_007 Hardly all.  Its popular, but I know far more than use Volley, or roll their own.  Retrofit has some major limitations (can't prioritize requests, can't override hashing, etc).  Basically if you want to do anything that's not the way Retrofit expects you're SOL.  I'd bet on less than 5% of major apps using it.  WHich doesn't mean you shouldn't if it fits your needs.

Comment: @GabeSechan Fair points. My only issue with Volley was the initial lack of fair documentation

Comment: @cricket_007 It also requires a bit of boilerplate.  I'd love to see someone come up with a layer on top of volley that works similarly to Retrofit's endpoints that can be optionally used.  That might be the best of both worlds.

Comment: @GabeSechan OkHTTP can be configured into Volley, if that's what you mean